# How to animate percentage width of two divs using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs here. first time the first div is not visible and the right div width is 100%.
when on click event the left div animate from left, then the right div width will decrease based on left div. how can i make it possible

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" name="" value"toggle">
```

jQuery

```
$("#button").live('click',function() {
    $(".left").animate({
        width: "30%"
    }, 300 );
    $("right").animate({
        width: "70%"
    }, 300 
);
```

Comment: You could do this with `CSS` and only animate one element (if that is your preference)

Answer (score 2):

***[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/62H3U/1)***

### CSS

```
.main { width: 100%; height: 400px; position:relative; }
.main > div { float:left; height: 100%; }
.left { background: yellow; }
.right { background: red; width: 100%; position:absolute; left:0; z-index:-1; }
```

### jQuery

```
var toggled = true;

$('#toggle').click(function() {
    if (toggled) {
        $('.left').animate({ 'width': '100%' }, 1500);
        toggled = false;
    } else {
        $('.left').animate({ 'width': '0%' }, 1500);
        toggled = true;
    }    
});
```

The trick here is that you're only animating one object instead of two, which can be handy when there is a lot of load on the client browser. Here, the red square is positioned behind the yellow, but initially the yellow square has no width.

Comment: thats demo is good but i cant use the absolute position. when on click event left div must be 30% and right one must be 70%. on the second click event left div goes to 0% and right one must 100%. please give me a solution

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, what about a pure CSS solution!

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KRb3/)

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' id='click' /><label for='click'>Click Me!</label><br /><br />
<div class='progress'>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#click{
    display:none;
}
label{
    border:1px solid teal;
    background:lightblue;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    font-family:arial;
    opacity:.7;
    cursor:pointer;
}
label:hover{    
    opacity:.8;    
}
label:active{    
    opacity:1;    
}
#click:checked ~ .progress div{
    width:30%; /* <--- whatever the amount you want to animate */
}
.progress{
    background:red;
    height:25px;
}
.progress div{
    background:green;
    height:100%;
    width:0;
    transition:width 250ms ease-in;
}
```

Comment: +1 for CSS animation. CSS animations are more performant than JS animations. I would toggle class with jquery but do the animation with CSS.

Comment: @HenriHietala - I concur, the benefit being JS will allow for greater control over the %/amount to animate

Comment: Really nice solution, out of interest what is the '~' in : #click:checked ~ .progress div {} doing?

Comment: Its a general sibling selector- see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 0):

try this code [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/xLHb8/)

```
<div>
    <button id="show_hide_button">click me</button>
</div>
<div id="some_box"></div>
<div id="some_other_box"></div>

var collapsed = false;
$('#show_hide_button').click(function() {
    if(!collapsed){
        $('#some_box').animate({width: '0%'});
        $('#some_other_box').animate({width: '100%'});
    } else {
        $('#some_box').animate({width: '25%'});
        $('#some_other_box').animate({width: '75%'});
    }
    collapsed = !collapsed;
});


html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#some_box {
    background: #fc0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}
#some_other_box {
    background: #0cf;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: this demo is ok but its not working properly. need to work like toggle left on click event